# Stationary Distribution of Doubly Stochastic Markov Chain

Tags: probability

For a doubly stochastic markov process defined by a n by n transition matrix, does the stationary distribution go to p = 1/n for each state?  If so, why?

Answer (score 1):

It has been answered several times here. Still for completeness I am answering it

- we will prove that $[\frac{1}{n} ,\frac{1}{n} ,...,\frac{1}{n} ]$ satisfies $\pi P =\pi$
- consider arbitrary $j  \in \{1,2,..n\}$
- $ \sum_i \pi_i p_{ij} = \sum_i \frac{1}{n} p_{ij} =\frac{1}{n} \sum_i p_{ij}  = \frac{1}{n} . 1 = \pi_j$ (because for doubly stochastic matrix $\sum_i p_{ij} = 1$)
- since this holds for arbitrary j.We are done
- your finite markov chain can have multiple stationary distributions. one sufficient condition for unique stationary distribution is irreducibility 
  \begin{bmatrix}
  0.5 & 0.5  & 0   & 0 \\ 
  0.5 & 0.5 & 0  & 0 \\ 
   0& 0 &0.5  &0.5 \\ 
   0&0  &0.5  &0.5 
  \end{bmatrix} there are many stationary distributions for this doubly stochastic matrix